# conflicting warnings with clang when using Weverything and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, compiler-warnings

when compiling the following code with clang 3.8 with `-Weverything -std=c++11`:

```
static void foo(long long) {}
int main() { foo(0ll); }
```

I get the following warnings:

`warning: 'long long' is incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat-pedantic]`

Is this a diagnostics bug? (`-Wc++98-compat-pedantic` included in `-Weverything` in C++11 mode)

Reproduce it [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CSwwevXHLCdBaczV)

Comment: Plain `-Weverything` is not supposed to be used in production on its own, it enables literally every diagnostics, many of which you don't care about; like `-Wpadded`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen indeed this was a duplicate to the other question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

Even though you've specified that the standard is C++11 you've also explicitly said that you want to enable *all* warnings.

To quote the doc:

> In addition to the traditional -W flags, one can enable all
>   diagnostics by passing -Weverything. This works as expected with
>   -Werror, and also includes the warnings from -pedantic.

This has no effect on what standard you're using to compile, `-Wc++98-compat-pedantic` *explicitly* says "check if my code is compatible with C++98", so that's what it does.